# How to pronounce these six difficult-sounding Arabic letters?

Tags: quran, reading-quran, education

i'm new here.
Can you tell me on how to pronounce these six difficult-sounding letters from the Quran: ص, ض, ط, and ظ?
But tell me with easy ways.

Thank you if answered!

Comment: Search youtube videos and see. Some videos describe with pictures

Comment: @AmerYR that might be a good advise for the first step learning Arabic, but not for learning qur'an recitation. As the qur'an must be learnt by oral transmission from teacher to student.

Answer (score 3):

First note that your question title is asking about 6 letters while the content only reveals 4!

The best way is to look for a hafidh who has a connected chain to the prophet and learn from him the so called makharij al-Huruf مخارج الحروف first. 
See also [Need proper pronunciation of various Arabic alphabets to read Quran correctly](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37481/need-proper-pronunciation-of-various-arabic-alphabets-to-read-quran-correctly/37482#37482)

IMHO ظ is the only difficult letter among the quoted ones. All others have more or less close equivalents in latin:

> ط an emphasized "t" (like in **t**alk)
>   ض an emphasized "d" (like in **d**oor)
>   ص an emphasized "s" (like in **s**orry)

The letter ظ is mostly close to an english "th" with a d-sound (not a t-sound) in the background.

Further more the letters that usually cause issues are:

> غ (some languages just don't have this sound)
>   ذ vs ز vs ظ the main difference is in a nuance of the pronunciation.
>   ض vs د (however I listened to a Turkish imam who confused ض with ط (so a confusion based on the notation is also possible and might be the reason for asking this question).
>   ت vs ث (vs in cases ط) which usually are difficult even for some Arabic natives.
>   س vs ص (vs ش for those who mistake in the notation)
>
> Some other possible mistakes due to the similar notation could occur for:
>   ق and ف
>   ع and غ
>   ج, ح and خ
>   ر and ز